Stata stacked bar chart with combination of two variables
I have a dataset that looks similar to the following



value
component
grade




16
component 1
6


12
component 2
6


15
component 3
6


25
component 1
7


68
component 2
7


54
component 3
7


25
component 1
8


98
component 2
8


10
component 3
8



from this, I would like to generate a stacked barChart with grade as the x-axis and
the values by condition stacked on the y-axis.
It should look something like this.
I tried with graph bar, over(value) over(grade) stack asyvars
But that resulted in the stacked values all being the same size and not grouped by components but by values


Perhaps
graph bar [fw=value], over(component) over(grade) asyvar stack

will get you closer.

Thank you, @Nick Cox, you pointed me in the right direction.
However, your solution resulted in a wrong scale for the y-axis.
I needed to omit the weight from it to work.
graph bar value, over(component) over(grade) asyvar stack

Good that you solved your problem. I don’t think your question was clear enough for anyone to know exactly what you wanted.

Yes, sorry. I felt that I could not express myself well enough when I asked but could not come to a better description. Thank you for your answer though.
